# Xcode 12.4 debugger doesn't show local variables in debug area

Tags: ios, swift, debugging

Alright, folks, I am facing strange issues in Project X:-

- Xcode 12.4, does not show any local variables while debugging, it's just completely blank or if I `select all` from `output window` it shows the registers variables.
- Also using po/vo in debug console show blank result.

**All of my projects are running on Debug mode,  Optimization Level was set to "None" for debug**

[image: Screenshot]

**NOTE:-**

I have another Project Y which is running on same xcode version 12.4, it has no issue. I can actually debug the variables and can print the variables.

The difference between Project X & Y :-

1. Project X supports both SPM and Pod
2. Project Y supports only Pod

I will be glad, if anyone can point out what am I missing here or help me to find a solution.

Thanks ;)

Comment: It certainly looks like you don't have debug info.  When you stop here, do you see source in the source display or just assembly?

Comment: I put a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad()` method of a viewController, even though I put breakpoints in any part of the codebase, I can't po any variable or see the content of local variables  . @JimIngham

Comment: @Vizllx, did you find a solution? I have the same problem.